# I can't get my Broadcom BCM4331 wifi on 14.04 to work

Tags: wireless, broadcom, macbook-pro

I just installed 14.04 on my mid 2012 model macbook last night, and I love it. Except for the fact that I've spent the last 24 hours trying to get my wifi to work.

Here's some info:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n (rev 02)
```

I've tried everything on this site, except:

> Uninstall the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package by issuing the following
>   command on a terminal:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
> ```
>
> Make sure that the `firmware-b43-installer` and the `b43-fwcutter`
>   packages are installed (of course you will need internet by others
>   means):
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer b43-fwcutter
> ```
>
> Type into terminal:
>
> ```
> cat /etc/modprobe.d/* | egrep 'bcm'
> ```
>
> (you may want to copy this) and see if the term 'blacklist bcm43xx' is
>   there. If it is, type:
>
> ```
> cd /etc/modprobe.d/
> ```
>
> and then
>
> ```
> sudo gedit blacklist.conf
> ```
>
> put a `#` in front of the line: `blacklist bcm43xx`, then save the
>   file (I was getting error messages in the terminal about not being
>   able to save, but it actually did save properly).
>
> reboot

Will this work? If not, can someone please suggest a solution?

Comment: Did you enable wifi through both function keys and network settings? check whether you enable wifi from network settings.(System settings->network).there have a small slider to enable or disable wifi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just copied the driver information from the lspci command, and searched it on this site. I found the answer in *[Wi-Fi working on Macbook Pro 8.2 on Ubuntu 12.04](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12042532)*.

I had to change a few things to make it work for me. Here's what I did:

Run the following in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
sudo dpkg-reconfigure firmware-b43-installer
```

And a lot of extracting will happen.

Then enter:

```
dmesg | tail -2
```

You'll get a response like this:

```
[ 5866.172626] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[ 5870.282827] applesmc: FS! : read arg fail
```

Comment: What's `dpkg-reconfigure firmware-b43-installer` supposed to do? That command is rather pointless without instructions about which options the reader is supposed reconfigure.

Answer (score 1):

1. First update apt-get:

   `apt-get update`
2. Then update Linux Image, Linux Headers (this code will determine **your** systems necessary headers) and install Broadcom DKMS:

   `apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') broadcom-sta-dkms`
3. Remove any possible active drivers for the Broadcom WiFi adapter:

   `modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac bcma`
4. Activate the wl driver for the Broadcom WiFi adapter:

   `modprobe wl`
5. Always best to reboot your system after things like this:

   `reboot`

Answer (score 0):

My script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
#
# install_bcm43xx_firmware
#
# This script tries to download and install the firmware needed to run
# WLAN cards using Broadcom's bcm43xx chips.

# firmware for b43
URL1=http://www.lwfinger.com/b43-firmware
FILE1=broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2
FIRMWARE1=broadcom-wl-5.100.138/linux/wl_apsta.o

# firmware for b43legacy
URL2=http://downloads.openwrt.org/sources
FILE2=wl_apsta-3.130.20.0.o

test -z "$( type -p curl)" && { echo "'curl' is not installed, aborting. Please install 'curl' and try again."; exit 1; }
test -z "$( type -p b43-fwcutter)" && { echo "'b43-fwcutter' is not installed, aborting. Please install 'b43-fwcutter' and try again."; exit 1; }
test -d /lib/firmware || mkdir -p /lib/firmware

TMPDIR=$(mktemp -d /var/tmp/bcm.XXXXXX) || exit 1

pushd $TMPDIR >/dev/null

echo "Downloading b43 firmware"
curl -# -f -o $FILE1 $URL1/$FILE1
if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
    echo "Extracting b43 firmware"
    tar xjf $FILE1
    b43-fwcutter -w /lib/firmware $FIRMWARE1
else
    echo "Could not download b43 firmware. Please look at /usr/share/doc/packages/b43-fwcutter/README."
fi

echo
echo "Downloading b43legacy firmware"
curl -# -f -o $FILE2 $URL2/$FILE2
if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
    echo "Extracting b43legacy firmware"
    b43-fwcutter -w /lib/firmware $FILE2
else
    echo "Could not download b43legacy firmware. Please look at /usr/share/doc/packages/b43-fwcutter/README."
fi

echo
if [ -d /lib/firmware/b43 ] ; then
    echo "b43 firmware successfully installed."
    sync && sync
    /sbin/modprobe -r b43
    /sbin/modprobe b43
else
    echo "b43 firmware installation failed."
fi
if [ -d /lib/firmware/b43legacy ] ; then
    echo "b43legacy firmware successfully installed."
    sync && sync
    /sbin/modprobe -r b43legacy
    /sbin/modprobe b43legacy
else
    echo "b43legacy firmware installation failed."
fi

popd >/dev/null
rm -rf $TMPDIR

exit 0
```

To use, copy the content into a local file with this name:

```
install_bcm4331.sh
```

Then make the file executable

```
chmod +x install_bcm4332.sh
```

Then run the script

```
sudo ./install_bcm4332.sh
```

If you want to run the script when you start the system, copy the file to the /etc/rc.d/init.d/ directory.