# No option to connect to hidden network Ubuntu 14.0.4

Tags: 14.04, networking

I finally managed to triple boot OSX, Windows, and Ubuntu on my MBP (have been working at this for a while). However, when I boot into Ubuntu and try to connect to my hidden wireless network there is no option for hidden networks. It only has options for configuring VPN and a manage network button. I have tried the manage network button and creating a new WiFi connection using the network name and security info but there is no connect option, I can only save and then it does nothing. I am new to Linux so maybe I am overlooking something. Any thoughts?

Comment: In Unity's network manager indicator should have an option "Connect to hidden WiFi network" or similar. Are you sure it is not there?

Comment: ![Here](https://goo.gl/photos/qnBuVHHj41WhQvNV7) is every option I have for networks from the indicator and the settings menu.

Comment: It says "No network devices available". What is the output of running the command `iwconfig`, `ifconfig` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` in a terminal?

Comment: [This](https://goo.gl/photos/zFpfQHbcxhc3ky7X7) is the output I got from running those commands.

Comment: What do `rfkill list` and `sudo lshw -C network` say?

Comment: [Here](https://goo.gl/photos/G6wajeL9i9EDWsjP7) is that output.

Comment: You need a driver for your Broadcom BCM4331 wireless card. Try the suggestions here to install it: http://askubuntu.com/q/590947/367990

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Byte Commander. I did indeed need a driver for my Broadcom BCM4331 wireless card. After some research, I found that the driver I needed was on the bootable USB I had installed Ubuntu from, it just wasn't installed for some reason. So, I was able to simply navigate to the pool folder on the bootable USB and install dkms from the main/d folder and the bcmwl-kernel-source from the restricted/b folder. Right after the second install the wireless networks appeared and I was able to connect to my hidden network.